# Latex how to cite a source for a table

Tags: latex

The goal is for the output to resemble something like the following where you have a '1' on the top and on the bottom it refers to the '1' providing more information.

[image]

Now, my values in the table are different, but it should still resemble that image.

```latex
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Atomic Numbers and Melting Points in Kelvin of Elements O, S, Se, Te, and Po.\label{table:elements}}
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={|c|c|c|},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=black!15}
            }
        \toprule
        Element &   Atomic Number   & Melting Point (K) \\
        \midrule
        Oxygen       &  8       &   54.8            \\
        Sulfur       &  16      &   388.36          \\
        Selenium     &  34      &   494             \\
        Tellurium    &  52      &   722.66          \\
        Polonium     &  84      &   528             \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: In other words, you want to use superscripted numerals for footnotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that there is a better way, but this is what I did.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    urlcolor=blue        % color of external links
}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Atomic Numbers and Melting Points in Kelvin of Elements O, S, Se, Te, and Po.\textsuperscript{1}}
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={|c|c|c|},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=black!15}
            }
        \toprule
        Element &   Atomic Number   & Melting Point (K) \\
        \midrule
        Oxygen       &  8       &   54.8            \\
        Sulfur       &  16      &   388.36          \\
        Selenium     &  34      &   494             \\
        Tellurium    &  52      &   722.66          \\
        Polonium     &  84      &   528             \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \footnotesize{\textsuperscript{1}Periodic Table, \color{blue}\uline{\url{https://ptable.com/\#Properties}} \color{black}(accessed September 12, 2022)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The syntax `\footnotesize{...}` is wrong. `\footnotesize` is a switch and does not take an argument. You should use `{\footnotesize ... \par}` instead.